# ViewController load methods called when view disappears?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I've got the following code in a viewController. I've got a NavigationController on the view (which is the child view - the code for the parent is working fine)

What happens is when I select an option on the parent, this viewController loads. The user can select an option from the child viewController to open a PDF file with a DocumentInteractionController (which works fine).

The problem is when I try going back to the parent viewController, messages are being sent to the child viewController as if it's still allocated. I saw something similar when I set it up since there were multiple calls to the methods in the child viewController.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize node;
@synthesize replies;
@synthesize docController;

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.docController init];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [self.docController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.replies == nil)
    {
        self.replies = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        self.actions = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    }
    if(self.replies.count == 0)
    {
        self.replies = [self.node nodesForXPath:@"./question/reply/text" error:nil];
        self.actions = [self.node nodesForXPath:@"./question/reply/response/action" error:nil];
    }

    return self.replies.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"QuestionCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Get the object to display and set the value in the cell
    NSString *cellText = [[replies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellText;
    return cell;
}

- (void) showOptionsMenu:(NSString *) fileName
{

    NSString *fileToOpen = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileToOpen];

    self.docController = [self setupControllerWithURL:fileURL usingDelegate:self];

    bool didShow = [self.docController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150) inView: self.view animated:YES];

    if(!didShow)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Sorry, app not found" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *action = [[self.actions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];
    [self showOptionsMenu:action];
}

- (UIDocumentInteractionController *) setupControllerWithURL: (NSURL *) fileURL usingDelegate:(id <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>) interactionDelegate
{
    UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileURL];
    interactionController.delegate = interactionDelegate;
    return interactionController;
}


@end
```

**EDIT**

Adding the code for the parent view controller...maybe there's something I'm doing wrong in there? I'm using GDataXML to load a Q&A app based on the contents of an XML file...

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize currentReply;
@synthesize questions;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setUpQuestions];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) setUpQuestions
{
    // create and init NSXMLParser object

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"query" ofType:@"xml"];
    NSData *xml_data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSError *error;
    GDataXMLDocument *xmlDoc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xml_data options:0 error:&error];

    NSArray *rootDataArray = [xmlDoc.rootElement nodesForXPath:@"//query" error:nil];
    for (GDataXMLElement *rootDataElement in rootDataArray)
    {
        // Allocate the query object
        self->query = [[[Query alloc] init] autorelease];

        // Name
        NSArray *query_title = [rootDataElement elementsForName:@"text"];
        if (query_title.count > 0)
        {
            GDataXMLElement *queryTitle = (GDataXMLElement *) [query_title objectAtIndex:0];

            self->query.queryTitle = [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:queryTitle.stringValue] autorelease];
        }


        NSArray *query_first_question = [rootDataElement elementsForName:@"question"];
        NSArray *replies = [NSArray alloc];
        questions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        if(query_first_question.count == 1)
        {
            GDataXMLElement *fq = (GDataXMLElement *) [query_first_question objectAtIndex:0];
            replies = [fq elementsForName:@"reply"];
            for (GDataXMLElement *replyElement in replies)
            {
                [questions addObject:replyElement];
            }
        }
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Only one section.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch(section)
    {
        case 0:
            return questions.count;
            break;
        case 1:
            return 1;
            break;
    }

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"QuestionCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    }

    // Get the object to display and set the value in the cell.
    GDataXMLElement *questionAtIndex = questions[indexPath.row];
    NSString *cellText = [[[questionAtIndex elementsForName:@"text"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellText;
    //cell.textLabel.text = [[questionAtIndex elementsForName:@"text"] objectAtIndex:0];
    return cell;
}


- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //NSMutableString *msg = [NSMutableString new];
    //[msg appendString:@"You selected row: "];
    //[msg appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",indexPath.row]];

    //UIAlertView *alertMsg = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Row Selected" message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    //[alertMsg show];
    if (questions != nil)
    {
        GDataXMLElement *selectedReply = (GDataXMLElement *) [questions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
        dvc.node = selectedReply;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
        [dvc release];
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I've tried profiling and looking for zombies, but when the crash occurs there are no zombie objects flagged. It throws the following error in the console:

```
[UIView _forgetDependentConstraint:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1e8ab810
```

Comment: What are the messages being sent or the methods called to the child viewController?

Comment: I'm trying to figure that out - there's some output in the output window, but it doesn't tell me the message being sent. It definitely looks like it's a call back into the child. For the record, I'm not using ARC.

Comment: It looks like there's a call to _forgetDependentConstraint but I can't figure out where it's coming from...

Comment: @Tim : Are you using "Auto Layout" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have seen this Issue before also !!!

**Answer :** `Turn Off "AutoLayout".`

I am guessing the error occurred due to new feature in `ios` called `AutoLayout`. It looks like Compiler has created some `NSLayoutConstraint` objects and due to some reason the objects were released more than they should. Deletion and Re-Creation, forces `Xcode` to Re-Build the Constraints. But,I am not 100% sure.

Try to **[Un-Check "AutoLayout"](http://www.goodbyehelicopter.com/2012/02/arggh-xcode-4-3-auto-layout-is-on-by-default-how-to-turn-off-auto-layout/)**, if it can solve your Problem.

Comment: this sounds like it's worth a shot. Where is the AutoLayout option? (I'm relatively new to XCode)

Comment: @Tim : Check here : http://www.goodbyehelicopter.com/2012/02/arggh-xcode-4-3-auto-layout-is-on-by-default-how-to-turn-off-auto-layout/

Comment: That was the problem! Now my code is working as expected! Thanks, Vin!

Answer (score 0):

Your DetailViewController code is fine - not actually fine, as you're leaking self.replies and self.actions, and the [self.docController init] is very odd and probably wrong (always alloc and init together) - but the lifecycle code on this end looks fine. The problem is almost certainly in the parent view controller (or possibly the document controller if you're creating a retain cycle there). If the parent view controller is holding onto a pointer to the detail view controller, it won't actually be deallocated and accessing the view or any property thereof will cause -viewDidLoad to be called again.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, your parent view controller is setting the node here:

```
    dvc.node = selectedReply;
```

and it's never being released from your DetailViewController.

I'm assuming that your GDataXMLElement in the DetailViewController header is set as "retain".

And there's some leaking problems as icodestuff pointed out.